# Trying to start Tor but Firefox starts instead

Tags: windows, firefox

After clicking on "Start Tor browser" Firefox starts but not Tor. Problem started after update about 2 weeks ago. Using Windows 7. Tried reinstalling Tor but problem remains. There are no error messages. How can I get Tor to start?

Comment: Going to need more details here, first of all did you make any changes to Tor Browser and if not, what happens if you perform a [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) then try installing and running Tor Browser?